# How can I pass an argument while writing a file using python

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I am trying to over-write a file using python and my code looks something like this:

```
from sys import argv
script = argv
Configuration_file = 'C:/Python33/argv.txt'
f= open(Configuration_file,'w')
f.write('script')
```

and when I try to run the file using command prompt by using the command

python argvnew.py roshan,

where argvnew.py is my python file and roshan is my argument. I expect that roshan replaces anything that is written within the argv.txt file mentioned in the program.

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes, it worked after a small modification in the script

from sys import argv
system = argv[1]
Configuration_file = 'C:/Python33/argv.txt'
f= open(Configuration_file,'w')
f.write (system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get arguments by calling `sys.argv[]` array.

`sys.argv[0]` means script name itself.

You can then write it back to your file, open the file such as [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open).